# Why is this edge not straight when using subgraphs in layered layout?

Tags: graphs, tikz-graphs

The MWE below produces a simple graph. When I add the two upper nodes A1 and B1 to a subgraph the horizontal alignment is lost which is understandable, since the nodes in the subgraph are positioned independent of the others. What I don't understand is that the connection from B1 to B3 is not straight anymore.
How can I fix this while keeping the subgraph?

Note: I need to use subgraphs in a much more complex example where I get the same Problem.

```
\documentclass[border=0.125cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,quotes} 
\usegdlibrary{trees,layered,force}
\begin{document} 
\tikz \graph[layered layout] { 
    "A1";
    "B1";    
    "B3";
    "A2";
    "A3";
    "C";  
    "A2" -- "A3";
    "A3" -- "C";
    "B1" --[minimum layers=2] "B3";
    "A1" -- "A2";
    "B3" -- "C";
};
\tikz \graph[layered layout] { 
//[layered layout]{
    "A1";
    "B1";
    };
    "B3";
    "A2";
    "A3";
    "C";     
    "A2" -- "A3";
    "A3" -- "C";
    "B1" --[minimum layers=2] "B3";
    "A1" -- "A2";
    "B3" -- "C";
};
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Though the question is not new I'm still hoping for some help. The problem is simple enough that other users might run into it. The graphdrawing library is a great alternative to graphviz but this bug makes it unusable for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A late workaround: set `bend left=0` for this edge or all edges:

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=0.125cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,quotes} 
\usegdlibrary{trees,layered,force}
\begin{document} 
\tikz \graph[layered layout] { 
    "A1";
    "B1";    
    "B3";
    "A2";
    "A3";
    "C";  
    "A2" -- "A3";
    "A3" -- "C";
    "B1" --[minimum layers=2] "B3";
    "A1" -- "A2";
    "B3" -- "C";
};
\tikz \graph[layered layout,edges={bend left=0}] { 
//[layered layout]{
    "A1";
    "B1";
    };
    "B3";
    "A2";
    "A3";
    "C";     
    "A2" -- "A3";
    "A3" -- "C";
    "B1" --[minimum layers=2, bend left=0] "B3";
    "A1" -- "A2";
    "B3" -- "C";
};
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Late but still relevant to me:) I accepted this answer since it solves the problem in the MWE. When I try it on my bigger graph it produces the error: "Dimension too large. <recently read> \pgf@xa". When I simplify the graph the error goes away at some point but I dont know how to isolate the probelem.